# EPPlus Saving file throws NULL reference exception

Tags: excel, save, pivot-table, nullreferenceexception, epplus

Saving Excel file that contains (even an empty) pivot table results in "Null Reference Exception" without any helpful message.

The image that shows the exception message is here below.

[image: Exception Message snapshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create pivot tables with EPPlus, make sure all your columns have **headers** (naming of the column as **first row**). Missing headers result in "null reference exception" when trying to save the file, even though all the rest of the application is perfectly functioning. What a devil.

Comment: You're a sanity saver. I was trying to add a list of years, without header, to my workbook and was getting `NullReferenceException` on save.